# What was the first anime to feature an OP/ED that was not performed by a Japanese group/artist?

Tags: music, anime-history

I noticed a few animes in the 00s feature Western opening and closing themes.

For example:

- Ergo Proxy's ending theme is Paranoid Android by Radiohead
- Speed Grapher's opening theme is Girls on Film by Duran Duran.

Both of which are pretty big names.

But, most anime usually have an artist/group performing the songs that hails from Japan.

**When did a track from the West first appear as an opening or ending to an anime?**

Comment: To clarify, is this specific to the Japanese version, or does this include the new openings bundled with dubbings? EG Pokemon, Dragonball Z

Comment: @Quill the original Japanese version (although, I'm sure dubs might be interesting too)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## *In your eyes* by *Samantha Newark* in Project A-Ko (1986)

The earliest use of an English song as an opening in the Japanese version of an anime I can find is *In your eyes* by *Samantha Newark* in Project A-Ko (1986), however, English songs were fairly common in versions *dubbed* for North America and Europe, often getting complete song rewrites instead of translations.

See the differences between Dragonball Z's English and Japanese openings for a good example of this.

Later on, however, when they stopped shipping new openings with anime (around 2000, for memory), English songs became more common, sporting names like Radiohead (**Ergo Proxy**, *2006*) and Oasis (**Eden of the East**, *2009*). An early and particular favourite of mine is **Serial Experiments Lain**'s opening, *Duvet* by *Boa* (*1998*).

Comment: Ah, I'd thought of "Duvet" when I saw this question as well!